# I have several dropdown list - I want to print out selected options of these dropdown lists

Tags: php, html

This is what I got so far, it's just the dropdown list. It's a form for making a reservation for appointment. I want to print out these selected values (= selected options of dropdown)
But I have no clue since I'm very new with PHP and HTML. Something with $_POST and $_GET ? Could I have some suggestions of solution? Much gratitude.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <select name="Ar" id="Ar">
<option value="1">2014</option>
<option value="2">2015</option>
<option value="3">2016</option>
<option value="4">2017</option>
<option value="5">2018</option>
<option value="6">2019</option>


</select>

        <select name="Manad" id="Manad">
<option value="1">Januari</option>
<option value="2">Februari</option>
<option value="3">Mars</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">Maj</option>
<option value="6">Juni</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">Augusti</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">Oktober</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>

</select>

        <select name="Dag" id="Dag">
<option value="1">Mandag</option>
<option value="2">Tisdag</option>
<option value="3">Onsdag</option>
<option value="4">Torsdag</option>
<option value="5">Fredag</option>

</select>

        <select name="Tid" id="Tid">
<option value="1">07:00</option>
<option value="2">08:00</option>
<option value="3">09:00</option>
<option value="4">10:00</option>
<option value="5">11:00</option>
<option value="6">12:00</option>
<option value="7">13:00</option>
<option value="8">14:00</option>
<option value="9">15:00</option>
<option value="10">16:00</option>
<option value="11">17:00</option>
<option value="12">18:00</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Boka" />




    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `<form>` tag. It should be wrapped around all your form-data (select, input) etc. Then you will fetch it using either `$_GET` or `$_POST` or even `$_REQUIRE`

Example (change site.php to whatever you please):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="site.php">
         <select name="Ar" id="Ar">
            <option value="1">2014</option>
            <option value="2">2015</option>
            <option value="3">2016</option>
            <option value="4">2017</option>
            <option value="5">2018</option>
            <option value="6">2019</option>
         </select>
         <select name="Manad" id="Manad">
            <option value="1">Januari</option>
            <option value="2">Februari</option>
            <option value="3">Mars</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">Maj</option>
            <option value="6">Juni</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">Augusti</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">Oktober</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
         </select>
         <select name="Dag" id="Dag">
            <option value="1">Mandag</option>
            <option value="2">Tisdag</option>
            <option value="3">Onsdag</option>
            <option value="4">Torsdag</option>
            <option value="5">Fredag</option>
         </select>
         <select name="Tid" id="Tid">
            <option value="1">07:00</option>
            <option value="2">08:00</option>
            <option value="3">09:00</option>
            <option value="4">10:00</option>
            <option value="5">11:00</option>
            <option value="6">12:00</option>
            <option value="7">13:00</option>
            <option value="8">14:00</option>
            <option value="9">15:00</option>
            <option value="10">16:00</option>
            <option value="11">17:00</option>
            <option value="12">18:00</option>
         </select>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Boka" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

PHP example:

```
if(isset($_POST['Ar'])) { // Make sure it's sent
    $year = $_POST['Ar'];
    echo "År: " . htmlentities($year); // Output (htmlentities for safety when outputting)

    $month = $_POST['Manad'];
    echo "Månad: " . htmlentities($month);
}
```

Comment: And how do I use those GET and POST more specifically? Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: There's an example. Note that you'll get the `value` from  `option` only, not the name of months/times.

Comment: But doesn't that only print out Ar? How do I add the rest of dropdown values?
There's an error with this line:
 $year = $_POST['Ar']); @Colandus

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. To print the rest you do the same, instead of `$_POST['Ar']` use `$_POST['Dag']` etc... Updated with one more print, you can figure the rest I hope.

Comment: Thank you, I got that part. But nothing happens when I click the button. Am I missing some GET function anywhere? I'm sorry but I'm very noob with PHP atm.

Comment: It should print out since it says echo, but I cannot see anything. @Colandus

Comment: If nothing happens when you click the button it means you did not properly wrap the `form` tag around the content.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I fixed the form issue. Thank you so much, Colandus.